# Sort A-Z big file between targeted Words

Tags: excel

I have a big text. There is an example I want to sort A-Z only numbers in this example I don't want to each time select and sort each Category, maybe it possible do in one action?

```
apple
20
50
10
40
oranges
30
10
50
60
Bananas
10
5
80
10
```

Comment: What have you researched? What have you tried? Would you use VBA?

Comment: not sure is VBA is the best option there are too  many random values

Comment: What do you mean, random values? Explain in your question. Check [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly. The way you have set up your data now is perfectly possible in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, your current data set-up is easily sorted through VBA. Couldn't help myself to throw together the following:

---

***<sub>Sample data:</sub>***

[image]

---

***<sub>Sample code:</sub>***

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range, area As Range
Dim lr As Long

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1)
    For Each area In rng.Areas
        area.Sort area
    Next area
End With

End Sub
```

---

***<sub>Result:</sub>***

[image]